# Load HTML with Ajax vs. load only data with Ajax and build the html with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, load

I'm working on a project which needs to load via **`AJAX`** some **`HTML`** information on the page.But I'm not quite sure how to load that information.

---

I don't know which method is better for me:

**1) Load the entire `HTML` with `AJAX` and then just append it to the page**

or

**2) Load only the data with `AJAX` and then build the `HTML` using `Javascript`(+`JQuery`)**

---

The one I tend to use is the **first method** because it's the easiest one but also it is more expensive regarding the `memory` (the biggest file I have to load has about `7kb` which is not too much)

---

**The second one** which is the hardest, involves a huge `Javascript` (`Jquery`) code to build the `HTML`(I have also to load the attributes for the element).And because I have lots of different `HTML` code to load I have to make lots of `conditions` (e.g. one for a `button`, one for a `title`, one for a `textarea` etc) and also I have to create `variables` that containes that `HTML`.

### My question is what method is the best to use in my case?

Comment: You need to be much more specific if you want people to be able to answer your question. What are you trying to implement?

Comment: I'm just trying to load some html on the page and i don't know which way is better:load plain html or just the data from html and then build it using javascript

Answer (score 3):

I would always stick to the solution where I cleanly divide data/logic and view. This would probably the case in the first alternative. Making changes to HTML generated with JavaScript is quite hard.

I'd suggest another option: Use client side templates. Load the template and the data with an ajax call and then fill out the template using javascript. There are some libraries out there for this scenario.

Comment: I agree with this answer. Just sending JSON and creating the html via a templating library is better from an architecture point of view. But if you have to update a small part of your page and don't have much use for a templating library in other parts of your app, you can just directly send the html.

Comment: I was also going to suggest templates. I've tried all three approaches. Imo the most important thing is to separate your code properly. It's hell having to edit HTML inside a bunch of JS.

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine a couple of developers working: A full-time back-end developer and a full-time front-end developer.
The BE developer has to send some data for the FE developer to display it right. Thinking of programming as easy as possible, he chooses the first method described by the OP. Everyone is happy.

A few months later, the presentation of this very data needs to be updated. The manager quickly calls the Front-End developer, which says:

"Uhhh... No can do. The entire data already comes formatted directly from the server."

Oh noes! Would this have happened if the data came only as RAW DATA from the server? I wonder =)

Comment: So which method do you choose regarding to your example? The second one?

Comment: Yes. I always chose that. The downside is it's more complicated, of course. But I believe that it's better because it's decoupled. In my opinion, you end up having less trouble.

Comment: My problem is that the html is parsed by the php(my own template engine) because i use a language select engine(also my own) so if I want to use RAW DATA I have to include also the file with the specific user language. What i noticed is that GitHub uses the first method to get data(plain HTML)

Answer (score 0):

the second method:

> Load only the data with AJAX and then build the HTML using Javascript(+JQuery)

is much appropriate, one main advantages of these method is your ajax response will become faster.
Also, it is more logical to separate the logic from design.

**Note**: always the best solution is depend on your specific case.